# How to mathematically prove that point charge and infinitesimal volume charge are same?

Tags: electrostatics, mathematical-physics, charge, mathematics, calculus

In electrostatics, while deriving certain elementary equations, I have seen all the books just ***assuming*** that point charge and infinitesimal volume charge are same.

How can we *rigorously*, *mathematically* and *formally* prove that point charge and infinitesimal volume charge are indeed the same?

Comment: What definitions are you using for each?

Comment: You can show that a spherical symmetrical charge density has the same potential outside of it as a point charge at the center. Are you refering to this?

Comment: > *"assuming that point charge and infinitesimal volume charge are same."* Could you give an example of derivation where this assumption is used? It is not clear what you mean by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxwell's equations, which are regarded as the fundamental equations governing the evolution of electromagnetic fields, are constructed in terms of charge density and current density. As such, electromagnetism is fundamentally described not in terms of point charges, but a continuous charge distribution.

In the language of distributions, a point charge is described by the *Dirac delta function* $\delta(\mathbf{r})$. This is defined as the *limit* of a sequence of charge distributions that are smaller and smaller, but contain the same total charge (and thus, have higher and higher charge density). Taking this limit gives you something like a charge distribution with infinitesimal volume and infinite charge density, but with a finite total charge.

Comment: I don't agree that you can somehow read off from Maxwell's equations that charge distributions should be continuous. Why can't they be distributions right from the start?

Comment: @Luke When I said "continuous" here, I didn't mean the mathematical definition of continuity, but rather simply that the charge density has a continuum as its domain, as opposed to a discrete set. I may have phrased that poorly, but I currently can't think of a better term.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Maybe something like: "not in terms of the positions of point charges, but in terms of a charge distribution $\rho(x)$ defined at all points in space $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$."

Answer (score 1):

The *Dirac delta function* formalizes this equivalence mathematically. It took mathematicians some time to make this object rigorous and led to the development of the *theory of distributions*.

**Addendum**

$\def\vr{{\bf r}}$The Dirac delta function is defined such that 
(1) $\delta(\vr) = 0$ everywhere except at $\vr={\bf 0}$, where it diverges, and (2)
$\int_V \delta(\vr) dV = 1,$
where $V$ is any volume containing the origin. 
Now consider the charge density
$$\rho(\vr) = q\delta(\vr).$$ 
This is a charge density which is zero everywhere except at the origin, where it diverges, and 
$$\int_V \rho(\vr)dV = q,$$
that is, the total charge is $q$. 
Thus, this is the charge density of a point charge with charge $q$ located at the origin.
All of this can be formalized rigorously using the theory of distributions.

Answer (score 1):

What is a point but an infinitesimal volume element?  Let your volume approach zero, and you have a point.